# 'Nonetheless' at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-starts

In some [nonetheless sentence examples](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/nonetheless), there is no sentence that begins with the word of *nonetheless*.

Can one use "Nonetheless" at the beginning of a sentence as follows?

```
It has been raining for a week. Nonetheless, we're going to try to go camping.
```

Is this grammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an adverb that can be used that way (i.e. as an interjection). However, in your example sentence, it may be more natural to use "nevertheless."

[Oxford English Dictionary's first examples](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.library.ubc.ca/view/Entry/127938?rskey=WPk18U&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) on the page for the adverb "nonetheless"/"none the less" actually begin with the word:

"1533   Aberdeen Burgh Rec. in A. J. Mill Mediaeval Plays in Scotl. (1927) 144   Nontheles he was ȝeit reddy to except the said office gif the toune [etc.].

"1620   tr. G. Boccaccio Decameron III. x   None the less he would do all that in him lay.""